# How to create one-to-many and many-to-many relations in Strapi v.4?

Tags: nested, many-to-many, one-to-many, strapi

I want to create relations between Post and Tag as follows.

1. Post has many Tags (one-to-many)
2. Tags have and belongs to many Posts (many-to-many)

I created collection types for Post and Tag.

[image]

[image]

Set them accessible for public user.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I created 1 post with 3 tags.

Now, when I try to see them at http://localhost:1337/api/posts
I don’t see nested elements, i.e. tags…
Am I missing anything ?

[image]

And lastly, I was not able to create Many-to-Many relations between Post and Tag with the following error.
I understand that **Tags** field already exists, but I thought this is how supposed to be set.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got reply from Strapi forum, so decided to share here.

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html

According to the docs above, to pull (in my case) 1st level nested elements I have to add `populate[0]` parameter like so:

http://localhost:1337/api/posts?populate[0]=tags

[image]